# Concept regarding authentication

Tags: authentication, owasp

I need to do some security validation on my program, and one of the things I need to answer, related to authentication is" Verify that all authentication decisions are logged, including linear back offs and soft-locks."

Does anyone knows what linear back off and soft-locks mean?

Thank you in advance,

Thais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing my research on OWASP ASVS. Actually Linear Back-of and soft-lock are authentication controls that are used to prevent brute force attacks and also can help against DoS.
Linear Back-of can be implemented through some algorithm by blocking user/IP for a particular time and after every failed login attempt that time is increase exponentially e.g. for first failed login block for 5 minute, for second failed login block for 25 minute for 3rd 125 min and so on. 
As per my understanding as I have seen in some articles and implemented in some application like Oracle WebLogic Soft lock is much easier to implement, IP Address (Which is I think is also helpful to protect against DoS and Brute force using automated tools) or user name is logged in database for every failed login attempt and when a certain threshold number of failed login attempts (e.g. 5)  block IP address permanently. Once the account has been soft locked in application runtime, it does not try to validate the account credentials against the backend system, thus preventing it from being permanently locked.
ASVS Verification requirement is very much clear on this though.
"Verify that a resource governor is in place to protect against vertical (a single account tested against all possible passwords) and horizontal brute forcing (all accounts tested with the same password e.g. “Password1”). A correct credential entry should incur no delay. For example, if an attacker tries to brute force all accounts with the single password “Password1”, each incorrect attempt incurs a linear back off (say 5, 25, 125, 625 seconds) with a soft lock of say 15 minutes for that IP address before being allowed to proceed. A similar control should also be in place to protect each account, with a linear back off configurable with a soft lock against the user account of say 15 minutes before being allowed to try again, regardless of source IP address. Both these governor mechanisms should be active simultaneously to protect against diagonal and distributed attacks."